# How to generate the API/developer key for Google APIs Client Library for PHP

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-maps-engine

I need to generate a simple API Key for me to be able to authenticate from Google App Engine/PHP via google-api-php-client and get the list of layers in maps engine the user has access to.

I am trying to follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_apikeys to create the simple API key (also known as a developer key in some other documents).

Step 3 of those instructions says:

...

3. In the sidebar on the left, expand APIs & auth. Next, click APIs. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the Google APIs Client Library for PHP.

...

But I can't find that API in the list of APIs!

Where is that API? 
Was it renamed or removed?
Do I need both the Google APIs Client Library for PHP key and also the Maps Engine API key, or just the Google APIs Client Library for PHP key?

What key do I have to put in 
$client->setDeveloperKey('?????????????????????');

Thank your for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that doc is slightly misleading. You do not need a separate key for the PHP client library, you only need a key for the Maps Engine API.

Make sure you've got that enabled and then any key you set up in the project console will work for any of the APIs you have enabled.

Comment: hi, tried with a maps engine api server key, too, to no avail.  I also tried without any developer key, too.

Comment: tried again, this time I changed the redirection URI to the same script and it worked, don't ask me why.  thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "Create a Project" on that page, then, once your project is created you will be able to sign up for an API key under the project in the left menu bar.

Comment: the project has already been created and I also have generated and tried server and browser keys for maps engine api and Key for server apps (with IP locking), but the question remains... what happened to the Google APIs Client Library for PHP API in the list of APIs and why is a simple API key fr this API mentiones in step 3 of the instructions